# use loader when click on a link in php

Tags: php, jquery

I need some help here please. I was trying to use loader, when click on a link that I have in php.

```
<?php

echo"<a href='actions.php?action=send&user=$user_id';><img src='img/connect.png' id='loading' onmouseover=this.src='img/connect_light.png' onmouseout=this.src='img/connect.png'></a><img src='img/post_loader.gif'  class='loading' width='20px;' height='12px;' style='display:none; margin-left:20px;' /> ";

?>
```

and I use the following script:

```
<script>
 $("#loading").click(function () {
 $(".loading").show();
 });
</script>
```

any idea why the loader is not working when clicking on the link. I use as style, the display:none;
If I remove it the loader appears working near to button. Any idea what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to attach jQuery handlers once the document is loaded. Try this:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#loading").click(function () {
        $(".loading").show();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: you are a genius my friend. Thank so mush ...saved me a lot of time